# Decreasing number at end of filename with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of png files, most of which have shared filenames distinguished by numbers. So for example I might have files:

- file_A_01.png
- file_A_02.png
- file_B_1.png
- file_B_2.png
- file_C.png

Unfortunately these were provided with the numbering system starting from 1 and I need it to start from 0. So I need my files renamed to:

- file_A_00.png
- file_A_01.png
- file_B_0.png
- file_B_1.png
- file_C.png

(Note that the number of leading zeroes in the final filenames do not matter, but I may have a mixture in the input filenames.)

I've found a lot of powershell solutions for removing or replacing parts of a filename, but nothing involving performing operations on numbers in the filename.

I tried to use regex to find the number and capture the match, but I don't know how to perform numerical operations on it. I got as far as:

```
Get-ChildItem *.png  |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "([0-9]+).png",'$1.png'}
```

Which of course doesn't do anything — it just matches the number, and then replaces it with that same number. I want to have something like `'$1'-1` at the end, but of course `$1` is a string. I'm not sure if I have to cast it to an integer, perform the operation, then cast back to a string and replace it, and if so I don't know how to do that. (I'm happy with a complete rewrite.)

Since I'm a complete beginner with powershell I'd prefer clarity over directness, and of course any explanations of the steps in a solution would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$Names = "file_A_01.png","file_A_02.png","file_B_1.png","file_B_2.png","file_C.png"

foreach($Name in $Names){
    $Number = [Double]$([Regex]::Matches($Name, "\d+")).Value
    if($Number -ne 0){
        $Number = $Number - 1
        $Name = $Name -replace $([Regex]::Matches($Name, "\d+")).Value , $Number
    }
    $Name
}
```

Comment: Answers my question perfectly (and very clear), though how might I change it to deal with filenames that contain other numbers? For example, if I had the file "file_A1_01.png" and wanted it to be something like "file_A1_0.png".

Comment: I would split it like this $Number = ($Name.Split("_")[2]).Replace(".png",""), after the $Number -1 I would put it back togeter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve leading zeroes (change `A:\` to your path):

```
PushD "A:\"
Get-ChildItem "file*_*[0-9].png" | Sort Name | ForEach-Object {
  $Number = ($_.BaseName -split '_')[-1]
  $Places = $Number.Length
  If ([Int32]$Number -gt 0) {
    $NewNum = ([Int32]$Number - 1).ToString('00000')
    $NewNum = $NewNum.Substring($NewNum.Length-$Places)
    $_|Rename-Item -NewName {($($_.BaseName) -Replace "$Number$","$NewNum")+$($_.Extension)} -Whatif
  }
}
PopD
```

Sample output:

```
PS A:\> .\SO_44717299.ps1
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: A:\file_A_01.png Destination: A:\file_A_00.png".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: A:\file_A_02.png Destination: A:\file_A_01.png".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: A:\file_B_1.png Destination: A:\file_B_0.png".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: A:\file_B_2.png Destination: A:\file_B_1.png".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: A:\file_C_001.png Destination: A:\file_C_000.png"
```

If the output looks OK remove the `-WhatIf` behind Rename-Item